Is the span of any 3 vectors 3-dimensional?
Is there a definitional limit attached to span or dimension that makes the question statement true?
Or, since the question doesn't specify linearly independent vectors or that the span's a basis, could I stick three [x, y] vectors in a set that has 3 vectors and a dimension of 2?

$(1,0,0)$, $(2, 0, 0)$, $(3,0,0)$

The question statement is false. If you were to have a set of three 2D vectors then the span of that set will have a dimension of at most 2. The dimension of a span of vectors must be less than or equal to the dimension of the vectors in the set. For example, with 3 <x,y> vectors, at least one of them can be made as a linear combination of the others.
